# Specific directory to Apache2/httpd (.bashrc)

Tags: linux, bash, apache, installation-path

I am trying to install apache on my /home/user1/.app/apache2/ by doing the following instruction during installation.

1. ./configure --prefix=/home/user1/.app/apache2/
2. make
3. make install

Apache was successfully installed but i was not able to allocated my httpd by doing 'which httpd'. I have done editing my .bashrc profile with and source .bashrc

```
export PATH=/home/user1/.app/apache2/bin:$PATH
```

May i know what's the problem i encounter here? Would be appreciate if anyone can help, I am new to Linux.

Comment: Problem solved. It just a typo error in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. According to the bash man page, .bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.

**What is a login or non-login shell?**

When you login (type username and password) via console, either sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: .bash_profile is executed to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.

But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window (xterm) inside Gnome or KDE, then .bashrc is executed before the window command prompt. .bashrc is also run when you start a new bash instance by typing /bin/bash in a terminal.

Comment: i found that there is a typo in my bashrc file. thank for the information anyway.